# Upload dynamic multiple files in Nest JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, nestjs

I'm trying to upload files with dynamic keys, but nest.js needs to know key names.

I tried this one:

```js
 @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
    async uploadFile(@Query() minioDto: MinioDto, @UploadedFiles() files: Array<BufferedFile>) {
        const {bucket} = minioDto;
        return (await this.minioClientService.upload(files, bucket))?.name;
    }
```

Here files are static, but I want dynamic like:

```js
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor())
    async uploadFile(@Query() minioDto: MinioDto, @UploadedFiles() files: Array<BufferedFile>) {
        const {bucket} = minioDto;
        return (await this.minioClientService.upload(files, bucket))?.name;
    }
```

I even tried to get files from the request
but I couldn't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can upload multiple files dynamically using `AnyFilesInterceptor` provided by nest.js like below:

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(AnyFilesInterceptor())
uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
  console.log(files);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is how we can upload the files, I have written the code to upload single and multiple files using NEST.JS:**

**app.controller.ts:**

```
 import { Controller, Post, UploadedFiles, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { FileInterceptor, FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { Express } from 'express';


    @Controller('api/portal/file')


    export class AppController {
      constructor(private appService: AppService) {}


      @Post('/multiple')
      @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
      async uploadFiles(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
    
// If you are getting the error "Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'" then replace "Array<Express.Multer.File>" with "any" or try to remove error by installing Express/multer

        const req = {
          files,
          prospectId: 1234,
        };
        return await this.appService.getUrls(req);
      }


      @Post('/single')
      @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
      async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
        const req = {
          files: [file],
          prospectId: 1234,
        };
        return await this.appService.getUrls(req);
      }
    }
```

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileDataReq, FileDataRes } from './dto/app.dto';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  async getUrls(uploadData: FileDataReq): Promise<FileDataRes> {
    const { prospectId } = uploadData;
    const response = { urls: [], prospectId };
    const { files } = uploadData;
    for (const file of files) {
      const { originalname } = file;
      let url = `/${prospectId}/${new Date().getTime()}_${originalname.trim().split(' ').join('_')}`;
      response.urls.push(url);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

**app.dto.ts:**

```
export class FileDataReq {
  files: Express.Multer.File[];
  prospectId: number;
}

export class FileDataRes {
  urls: string[];
  prospectId: number;
}
```

**Postman:**

**Multiple Upload:**
[image]

**SingleUpload:**
[image]